# How can I calculate geometric sequence in LaTeX?

Tags: math, command, latex, sequence

I am trying to make my own command to calculate geometric sequence in LaTeX example: 10*4^(n+1)
I've tried couple of things similar to this but non of them seemed to work:

```
\newcommand{\GeometricSequence} [1] {\the\numexpr 10*4^(#1+1) \relax \\}
```

So if type command (shown bellow) it should "print" 3360.

```
\GeometricSequence {3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) to perform standard floating point operations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand{\IntegerCalculation}[1]{\fpeval{10 * 4 ^ (#1 + 1)}}

\begin{document}

\IntegerCalculation{3} % 2560

\end{document}
```